# HTML Jquery volume function

Tags: jquery, html, function, onclick, volume

Here is my function that currently works.

```
$(function() {
    $("#myVideo").each(function() {
        this.volume = 0.0;
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#myVideo").click(function() {
        this.volume = 0.8;                            
    });
});
```

The first one sets the volume to 0 on load for my video. The 2nd function, onclick will set the volume to 0.8.

My Question: How can I click the picture once to set volume=0.8 and then click again to set the volume back to 0.0. And do this as many times as the user wishes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the first segment of the script, as it seems that you only care about the `.click` portion. What you can do is have a variable that alternates between `0.0` and `0.8`, and have that be the value the volume is set to. A rough mock-up is below:

```
var change = 0.8
$(function() {
    $("#myVideo").click(function() {
        this.volume = change;  
        if (change == 0.8) { change = 0.0 }
        else { change = 0.8 }                          
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need a toggle button.

```
var on = false;
$(function() {
    $("#myVideo").click(function() {
       on = !on;
       this.volume = (on) ? 0.8 : 0;                            
    });
});
```

Comment: So you can use an array approach there.